# How should I set up Laravel routes?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I'm having some difficulties with routes. Actually, I'm having difficulties with a lot of things in Laravel, some of which I've managed to wrap my head around (such as migrations, seeding and authentication) but this is one of the most basic ones.

I've been creating routes based on the one that comes with Laravel. However, after much googling, something seems off. I'm not sure this is how it should be done.

My current web.php file looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
});

Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});

Route::get('/student', function () {
    return view('profiles.student');
});

Route::get('/professor', function () {
    return view('profiles.prof');
});

Route::get('/profadmin', function () {
    return view('profiles.profadmin');
});

Route::get('/ident', function () {
    return view('pages.ident');
});

// Authentication
Auth::routes();

Route::post('/login', function () {
    return view('pages.ident');
});

Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');


// Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Route::get('/ident', 'HomeController@ident')->name('ident');
//
// Route::get('/aluno', 'HomeController@aluno')->name('aluno');
//
// Route::get('/ident', 'HomeController@ident')->name('ident');
```

Also, certain pages should only be viewed by authenticated users and I'm having a hard time understanding how exactly that is done and how the routes should reflect that.

I'm sorry if this is simple stuff, but this is my first time using a PHP framework. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read documentations when trying to use frameworks, study up first before asking questions on stackoverflow. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017 Follow laracast to learn Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets suppose you want to protect the `about` route

then in the web.php file, replace your `about` route with this:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('pages.about');
})->middleware('auth');
```

now anyone hits /about and not logged in, it will be redirected to /login

if you want to know more about authentication, Laravel documentation really the best place for you:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this before but it didn't work. It turns out there was something wrong with the authentication process itself too. Things are better now.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are beginner you should read Laravel documentation & Laracasts

In your routes you trying to show only views

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
   return view('pages.about');
});
```

In Laravel 5.6 you can do it like this

```
Route::view('/about', 'viewName');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware I could use Route:view. I've been going all over the documentation, but at times I find a bit hard to understand. Thanks for the answer :)